# SAL annotations and pointer parameters

Tags: c++, static-analysis, sal

I have been reading about [SAL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh916382.aspx) and I'm not clear on if annotations on pointer types apply to the reference or the value it points to. For example, if I have:

```
void f(_In_ type* t);
```

`_In_` means "The parameter must be valid in pre-state and will not be modified." Does its application here mean that the address of t will not change, or the value of t?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, `_In_` means that

- VS Code Analysis will validate that callers pass a non-null pointer to an initialized buffer.
- VS Code Analysis will **not** validate that `t` is checked for null before dereferencing it in the function; `t` is assumed to be non-null in the function itself. By changing `_In_` to `_In_opt_`, VS Code Analysis **will** validate that `t` is checked for null before dereferencing it.
- VS Code Analysis will validate that the function only reads "one element" of `type` from the memory pointed at by `t`, like assigning the value of the dereferenced pointer to a variable.